# Partial Marginalization of 3 variable conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a 3 variable (A,B,C) joint distribution function made according to the formula C := A + B; A and B are independent.
So, the probability distribution is:

```
A   B   C   P(A,B,C)
---------------------
0   0   0   0.25
0   1   1   0.25
1   0   1   0.25
1   1   1   0.25
```

And remaining cases have zero probability.

I'm trying to get the distribution obtained by marginalize the variable B

Now, P(A,B,C) = P(A).P(B).P(C|A,B)

If I try to marginalize this distribution with respect to B, I get:

P(A,C) = P(A).P(B=0).P(C|A,B=0) + P(A).P(B=1).P(C|A,B=1)

But I'm not sure how to get the final P(A,C) expression from that, because the final P(A,C) should have a distribution of:

```
A   C   P(A,C)
---------------------
0   0   0.25
0   1   0.25
1   0   0
1   1   0.5
```

I initially thought it would be P(A,C) = P(A).P(C|A), but it seems that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that because $C=A+B$ , then: $$~\mathsf P(C=z\mid A=x, B=y) ~ = ~ \begin{cases} 1 &:& x+y=z~,~x\in\{0,1\}~,~y\in \{0,1\}\\[0.5ex]0 &:& \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

So, therefore:  $$\begin{align} \mathsf P(A=x, B=y, C=z) ~ = ~ & \mathsf P(A=x) ~ \mathsf P(B=y) ~ \mathbf 1_{x+y=z} \\[1ex] = ~ & \tfrac 1 4 ~ \mathbf 1_{x\in\{0,1\}~,~y\in \{0,1\}~,~z=x+y}
\end{align}$$

Because $~\mathsf P(A=x)~=~\tfrac 12~\mathbf 1_{x\in \{0, 1\}}~$ and likewise for the p.m.f. of $B$.

$\Box$

Comment: I get you, but what about P(A,C)?

Comment: @Tapajit obvs. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A=x, C=z) ~=~& \mathsf P(A=x, B=z-x)\\~=~&\mathsf P(A=x)~\mathsf P(B=z-x)\\~=~& \tfrac 14 ~\mathbf 1_{x\in\{0,1\}~,~ z\in\{x, x+1\}}\end{align}$$